# Ionic 3 multi button pressing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, mobile, ionic3, multi-touch

I am developing ionic app, I need mobile game feature, when I hold 2 buttons I need to call one function with different parameters and start logging event to console, on pressend or touchend stop logging.

EXAMPLE - one button is pressed (e.g. left arrow) and I should be able to press next button (e.g. break button). Problem is when I hold pressing first button and I press secondone, application stuck and when I stop pressing, application call both functions alternately and never stop calling it on press or touch end.

Aplication behaves like app without multitouch. When I press only one button everything works clearly.

```
<button class="left_button"
           (touchstart)="buttonPressed('LEFT')" (touchend)="buttonEnd('Stop-left')"
           (mousedown)="buttonPressed('LEFT')" (mouseup)="buttonEnd('Stop-left')"
 >
<button ion-fab color="custom-secondary"
                  (touchstart)="buttonPressed('BREAK')" (touchend)="buttonEnd('BREAKE-END')"
                  (mousedown)="buttonPressed('BREAK')" (mouseup)="buttonEnd('BREAKE-END')"
          >
```

and functions

```
buttonPressed(event: string) {
this.buttonPressEvent = event;
this.isButtonPressed = true;
console.log("TEST _ ");
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
//CALLING SOCKET
  console.log("\t PRESSING - " + event);
}, this.globals.sendingDataInterval);}

buttonEnd(event: string) {
    this.isButtonPressed = false;
    console.log('STOP PRESSING' + event');
    //STOP CALLING SOCKET
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.buttonPressEvent = '';
  }
```